# Google Calendar API for iOS return BirthDays?

Tags: ios, google-calendar-api

I am trying to get birthdays from Google Calendar API for iOS application. Now i can get the Events from the Google Calendar.

```
- (void)fetchEvents {
GTLQueryCalendar *query = [GTLQueryCalendar queryForEventsListWithCalendarId:@"primary"];
query.maxResults = 10;
query.timeMin = [GTLDateTime dateTimeWithDate:[NSDate date]
                                     timeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];;
query.singleEvents = YES;
query.orderBy = kGTLCalendarOrderByStartTime;

[self.service executeQuery:query
                  delegate:self
         didFinishSelector:@selector(displayResultWithTicket:finishedWithObject:error:)];}

- (void)displayResultWithTicket:(GTLServiceTicket *)ticket
         finishedWithObject:(GTLCalendarEvents *)events
                      error:(NSError *)error {
    if (error == nil) {
        NSMutableString *eventString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        if (events.items.count > 0) {
            for (GTLCalendarEvent *event in events) {
                GTLDateTime *start = event.start.dateTime ?: event.start.date;
                NSString *startString =
                [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:[start date]
                                               dateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle
                                               timeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
                [eventString appendFormat:@"\n  %@\n  %@\n\n%@\n", event.summary, startString, event.descriptionProperty];

            }
        } else {
            [eventString appendString:@"No upcoming events found."];
        }

        NSLog(@"eventString %@",eventString);

    } else {
        [self showAlert:@"Error" message:error.localizedDescription];
    }
}
```

how to get the Birthdays from Google Calendar API for iOS.
I have go through this documentation for Google Calendar API:
**https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/ios**

Comment: could u help me in swift regarding google calendar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked on this before and this is what I found. Although present by default, Birthday events don't have valid 'eventIDs', which looks like 2016_BIRTHDAY_self (for this year), so when you fetch it using [Events: list](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list), nothing is returned. You have to add it first:

On your Google Calendar:

1. Click the default [birthday icon](http://imgur.com/GjPiqSA) in your Calendar.
2. Click 'Copy to my calendar'.
3. This will open the events UI. You can add additional details in the description. Then Save.

Now, a duplicate Birthday event is added to your calendar but this time, it has a valid eventID. So when you make another call using Events:list, it [returns the event](http://imgur.com/5L05qfm).

How to do this in iOS?

URI request:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId/events
```

You can [use NSURLConnection](http://codewithchris.com/tutorial-how-to-use-ios-nsurlconnection-by-example/):

```
// Create the request.
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"]];

// Create url connection and fire request
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

**Getting Birthday using People API:**

1.Set your birthday to public in Google+ [Basic Information](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1350405?hl=en) by ticking 'show year of birth'

2. Make use of People API URI request:

   GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/userId

Use the [Try-it](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get#try-it) to test it now with parameters:

```
userId -> me
fields -> birthday
Authorize and Execute.
```

Comment: So without creating event, Google Calendar API doesn't give Birthdays? @noogui

Comment: Yes, that's what i've found.

Comment: @MdBajlurRashid  you don't seem to agree?

Comment: I agree with you, but this is not the solution i want. Because i can't force the users to create birthdays as events. As google calendar shows birthdays on calendar, so google can provide some kind of APIs for that. So that through the users permission, app can have the access to user's contact birthdays. @noogui

Comment: That's the limitation of Calendar API. I suggest you use the People API instead. I was able to fetch my birthday easily. I've added that to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

it is **possible** to get all birthdays from google calendar **without copy** to your calendar

Get **birthday calendar** id From google.

- Open google calendar
- Click on birthday calendar settings

[image]

- You will get **calendar id** from **Calendar Address**
- Use that calendar id for fetching events

  ```
  You can also get Calendar id through Google API
  https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list
  ```

  For iOS check below code

  ```
  let query = GTLRCalendarQuery_EventsList.queryWithCalendarId("calendar id")
  service.executeQuery(
      query,
      delegate: self,
      didFinishSelector: #selector(displayResultWithTicket(_: finishedWithObject:error:)))
  ```

  Delegate method

  ```
  func displayResultWithTicket(
  ticket: GTLRServiceTicket,
  finishedWithObject response : GTLRCalendar_Events,
                     error : NSError?) {


     }
  ```

  its working for me

Thanks.

Comment: could u help me with google calendar in creating events

Comment: i only ran the google calendar code successfully and it is working fine